# Spring Security expired-url doesn't work

Tags: spring-security

I have a problem with Spring security, I try to redirect to login page when the user session was expired but it doesn't work. and I got this message when a user session was expired in my jsp page:

> Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

type Rapport d''exception

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

This is my spring-security.xml:

`

```
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none">
    <security:concurrency-control expired-url="/login?login_error=2"   />
    </security:session-management>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_RH')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/choix" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_RH')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/list" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_RH')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/listDemandeConge" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_RH','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/addcategorie" access="hasRole('ROLE_ACHAT')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login.do" 
    default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" 
    username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1"/>

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>
  <security:password-encoder hash="md5"></security:password-encoder>
  <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"  
        users-by-username-query="select Login, Password, CASE ENABLED WHEN 'active' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END 'ENABLED' from Utilisateur where Login=?"  
        authorities-by-username-query="select us.Login, ur.Libelle_Profil from Utilisateur us, Profil ur
          where us.id_utilisateur = ur.id_utilisateur and us.Login =?   " />


  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

`

Comment: Please provide a complete stacktrace

Comment: This  is my stacktrace :Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/application] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException